# Odd shaped Trapezoid

Tags: geometry

My wife and I are interested in buy a piece of land that is an odd shaped trapezoid. Here are the lengths: B1=129.98ft, B2=72.9ft, S1=436.2ft, S2=445.36ft. The area is approx 1.02 acres. Basically the lot is wider in the front and tapers in the back. I am trying to determine the width of the lot at approx. 200ft back. None of the angles are known, but based on the plot map, none are 90 degrees. ? Is this possible to determine, if so, how?

Comment: Why not get the real estate agent to measure it for you?

Comment: Measure one diagonal (any) - you get two triangles where you could calculate the area of the two triangles - this site https://www.mathopenref.com/heronsformula.html will allow you make the calculation of the triangles area easy!

Comment: The tool is toward the bottom of page.

Comment: @Moti, Kenny is not asking for the area, Kenny is asking for the "width", "approximately $200$ feet back" (whatever that means).

Comment: There is a need to define WHAT is width. Knowing the area could help in determining a WIDTH.